# Associate sh files on Mac with correct application

Tags: macos, command-line

I am new to macOS. I created an sh file but associated it with an editor in order to modify it. But now it opens with the editor and does not execute any more. Please advise how to associate sh files with correct application as before the change.

Comment: Does the _shell script_ you created hav a `.sh` _extension_? If yes, just associate it with **Terminal** or remove the _extension_. If a _shell script_ is set _executable_ and has a proper _shebang_ and no _file extension_ it should automatically open in **Terminal**.  If the _shell script_ did not have an _extension_ when you associated with another _application_, then just change it's association back to **Terminal** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run shell scripts from Finder you need to

- make them executable with `chmod +x SCRIPT`
- give them a `.command` suffix with `mv SCRIPT SCRIPT.command`

To keep them as .sh files

- select one of them in Finder
- open the Info window (<kbd>Cmd-I</kbd>)
- change the associated application to Terminal.app

Comment: Thank you for your help nohillside. My question though was how to re-associate sh files with the default macOS application as now I am concerned I broke the operating system? There are other sh files that will not execute any more because of this change.... Just need to revert this modification

Comment: Just set "Open With" in Get Info to Terminal.....?

Comment: @User123 Not even sure .sh files execute by default. AFAIR I never changed the association for them, they open in Xcode here be default.

Comment: Perfect, thanks ! Set "Open With"=Terminal

Comment: RE: "To run shell scripts from Finder you need to" ... give them a `.command` suffix with `mv SCRIPT SCRIPT.command` --   To say you need to do this is is just not true. There is no hard requirement for a _shell script_ to have an extension, `.command` or otherwise, to run from **Finder** as long as it's made executable and is associated with **Terminal**.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, testing on a clean install of **macOS Big Sur** 11.4 (Intel) with no additional software installed and only the default installed software, a *shell script* made *executable* with a proper *shebang*, without an *extension* will by default be opened by and run in **Terminal** when *double-clicked* in **Finder**. One with a `.sh` *extension* will open by default in **TextEdit**.

Note that without a proper *shebang* it may not execute properly by itself.

A *shell script* with or without an *extension* can be associated with a different *application*, either individually or globally.

If you have associated your *shell script* with an *application* other then **Terminal**, or its default *application* and you want to associate it back to **Terminal**, or its default *application*, simply do it the same way you did it to begin with.

To change the association of a *file* in **Finder**, simple select the *file* and press **⌘I**, then on its *info sheet* change its **Open with:** *application* setting.

---

**Additional Information**

Installs of some software, **Apple** and or a *third-party application*, can change the association of a *shell script* with a `.sh` *extension* to something other then **TextEdit**. For example, installing **Xcode** will associate *shell scripts* with an `.sh` extension to it, taking it away from **TextEdit**.

A **user** can also change the default association at will.

For a global association change you can click the **[Change All…]** button, although do not do this if your are not sure of the action you are taking.

As a general rule, *shell scripts* should be run directly in **Terminal** and not from **Finder**. Opening for edit can be done easily in **Terminal** or **Finder**.